# Flutter firebase version conflict firebase messaging

Tags: firebase, flutter

I have a firebase flutter app, everything worked, but when I added firebase_messaging: ^5.1.4. The app gives this:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:preDebugBuild'.
> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[18.0.
  0]", but isn't being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will be unknown.

  Dependency failing: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:18.0.0 -> com.google.firebase:firebase-iid@[18.0.0], but fire
  base-iid version was 19.0.0.

  The following dependencies are project dependencies that are direct or have transitive dependencies that lead to the art
  ifact with the issue.
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_messaging' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging@18.0.
  0
  -- Project 'app' depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@17.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'cloud_functions' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-functions@17.0.0
  -- Project 'app' depends on project 'firebase_core' which depends onto com.google.firebase:firebase-core@16.0.9

  For extended debugging info execute Gradle from the command line with ./gradlew --info :app:assembleDebug to see the dep
  endency paths to the artifact. This error message came from the google-services Gradle plugin, report issues at https://
  github.com/google/play-services-plugins and disable by adding "googleServices { disableVersionCheck = false }" to your b
  uild.gradle file.
```

These are my other packages

firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+12
firebase_storage: ^3.0.4
cloud_firestore: ^0.12.7+1
cloud_functions: ^0.4.1+1

(they all work)

I have this in my build gradle:  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.0'

Is there a way of fixing this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Everything seems to be working fine for me. Are you sure that you have gone through the whole initial set-up process for firebase core and firebase messaging for both android and iOS?

Comment: Not for ios yet, because I need to have a developer account. Strange thing: when I add the version : firebase_messaging: ^4.0.0+4 it works..... Only a few 'errors' that a token isn't registered or something, but the app runs

Comment: I usually don't specify the version for the package, and it works most of the time. It seems to be a better practice to make the pubspec file handle the versions by itself. Of course, if you are not looking for specific feature of the version that you are trying to install

Comment: No, just wanting to have push notifications. When the pub handles the version it gives the same rror

Comment: But when I use the version 4, it gives an error while running and crashes the app when an notifications is send  Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseInstanceIDService>: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdService;

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently trying this:

in the app level build.gradle I have this:

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

I'm adding this:
        com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

(after apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services')

Answer (score 0):

Include Firebase Core dependency in pub spec.yaml and not specifying the versions of firebase dependencies resolve most of the issues.

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_core

Answer (score 0):

run these two lines

```
rm Podfile.lock
pod install --repo-update
```

these will does the job. it took my two days to fix it